# Can DARP be used for Non Emergency Medical Transportation problems?

Tags: routing, network, transportation

I have a Non-Emergency Medical Transportation (NEMT) business and am looking for the best solution that can automate the dispatching process. I looked over DARP and it seems fine. I need to know 2 things:

1. Does anyone know if DARP is a good fit for NEMT? NEMT is about transporting patients to their appointments with constraints like time window for pick up or delivery, max ride time, shortest distance, dynamic receipt of requests, etc.
2. Where can I find the source code for DARP?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that this site was not designed to collect private feedback via email.

Comment: Please don't say "reply your answers to x@y.com. This only leads to spam to your email. And people will use the answer box below."

Comment: What is DARP? Where have you found whatever information about it you have found so far? While your goals do have some elements in common with GIS in terms of network analysis and routing, it also seems to go a bit further - perhaps into specialized software for vehicle dispatch.

Comment: DARP = Dial-A-Ride-Problem. Generic term just like TSP.

Comment: @UffeKousgaard Ah, I've never seen that with P attached to the end. I did a search on the term and it was coming back with a bunch of results for a program in New York call the "Directed Accident Response Program". I thought it might have been an actual software program. Always best to spell out an acronym at least once as was done for NEMT. In GIS contexts the closest term I'm aware of is Esri's VRP or vehicle routing problem.

Comment: TSP, CPP, VRP, DARP, CVRP are all such "problems" in routing theory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DARP as a concept can be used for NEMT, since DARP aims at solving the problem even when new requests are added on-the-fly. We have been making experiments with our FleetEngine  (see www.routeware.dk) software for solving exactly NEMT tasks and depending upon which requirements you have, it can handle since it is generally build around solving Mixed Pickup and Delivery problems.

Comment: Thank you Uffe for the comments. DARP (Dial A Ride Problem) is an heuristic algorithm developed by Massachussets Institute of Technology (MIT) to solve the problem of scheduling of advanced requests using multiple vehicles with time window. It was introduced in 1984 (so old). I am wondering if anyone knows of a newer version or newer algorithm to solve the same problem. We are operating a non-profit transportation business for Non-Emergency Medical Transportation (NEMT). Dispatching is the most time consuming process in our business and we are looking to automate it with the best algorithm.

Comment: Well, our FleetEngine is one such algorithm to handle NEMT. It is not free and I am not going to claim it is the best. But considering the price, it is good value for money.

Comment: And how do I get my hands on FleetEngine to review it?

Comment: Fill in this form, and I'll get you a test license: http://www.routeware.dk/fleetengine/request3a.php